# How can I uninstall software from an RHEL 5 system?

Tags: redhat, rhel5, package-management, ruby, rubygems

I installed Rubygems 1.3.4 on an RHEL 5 system. The way you install that is to download source and run `setup.rb`. I did not find a package for it through `yum list available`.

Now I'd like to uninstall it because I've decided to use a different version of Rubygems. There is no install log file or any list of where the installer put stuff. It isn't immediately clear from looking at `setup.rb` where things went.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RubyGems 1.3.4 is the latest version. Generally, if you're going to use gems to install Ruby libraries, you'll want to run the latest possible version of it. If you're planning to install an RPM packaged version instead of the RubyGems-from-source, you should start by looking in `/usr/local/lib/site_ruby` and `/usr/lib/ruby/gems`.

Software you install outside 'rpm' and 'yum' (and up2date, though rarer) on RHEL won't be in the RPM database, so those tools won't know anything about it.

Comment: By "different version" I meant that I've installed Phusion's "Ruby Enterprise Edition" which comes with its own copy of RubyGems 1.3.4.

Answer (score 0):

This is really more of a ruby/gems question than a redhat/package-management question.

I believe you can use "`gem list`" and then "`gem uninstall NAME`" to remove any individual "gems" (ruby packages), but I don't know how you can uninstall gem itself.

gems is its own (broken) ruby-specific package-management system.  There's Ruby people that don't understand RPM well that think it's superior in ways that might be useful for programmers on a dev box but is mostly a pain for sysadmins on production boxes.

Comment: Gems are a great way to distribute Ruby libraries without having to repackage for every different platform's nuances and silliness. Yes it has faults, but its no less a viable language library packaging tool than Perl's CPAN or Python's EGG. It really has nothing to do with a superiority complex, as it is an ease of distribution.

Comment: @jtimberman: well, okay...  I don't install directly via CPAN or EGG on any RHEL/CentOS system I care about either: I make an RPM out of it and install that.

Answer (score 0):

To update rubygems itself, the best way is to install rubygems-update

```
sudo gem install rubygems-update
```

This will update your rubygems install to the latest version. It's as easy as that.